# Recuperar tabela MySql

Tags: mysql, wamp

Reinstalei o WAMP e não exportei a base de dados (.sql), porém tenho os arquivos ".ibd" e ".frm".

Após a instalação, criei uma base de dados em branco e copiei para a pasta todos os arquivos ".ibd" e ".frm", porém ao tentar abrir a tabela via phpmyadmin, um erro é retornado e informa que a tabela não existe.

Fiz um teste com a tabela mais pequena, apaguei os arquivos, criei a tabela e executei a query abaixo:

```
ALTER TABLE bd.tabela DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

Depois copiei os arquivos de backup ".ibd" e ".frm" para a pasta e executei a query abaixo:

```
ALTER TABLE bd.tabela IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

Porém há 2 problemas:

1. A base de dados possui várias tabelas e campos, não consigo recriar tudo, até porque não lembro de toda a informação.
2. No teste que fiz, a informação foi restaurada porém não foi inserida na respectiva coluna, ou seja, trocou a informação de várias colunas.

Com faço para restaurar a minhas tabelas e os respectivos dados?

Comment: A engine das tabelas era InnoDB?

Comment: @rafaels88 sim, era.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse cara: http://www.hexblot.com/blog/recovering-innodb-tables-ibd-and-frm-files

Answer (score 1):

Nao sei se pode ajudar, mas aqui a traduçao de um documento que explica como fazer:

*Antes de começar, você deve parar o WAMP.
No seu servidor antigo (em sua chave SD / USB externo) ou armazenado seu site, navegue até a pasta de dados MySQL. O caminho deve ser semelhante a este "D: \ wamp \ bin \ mysql \ mysql5.1.53 \ data \" ou "mysql5.1.53" indica a versão do MySQL instalado dados anteriores.
Dentro da pasta de dados, deve haver vários arquivos e pastas. Os arquivos contêm bases de dados de sites existentes e contêm um monte de arquivos com a extensão .frm que precisamos. Você deve reconhecer os nomes de arquivos ou banco de dados que você está familiarizado.
Copie a pasta que contém os dados de seu site e todo o seu conteúdo para os dados da pasta diretamente para sua nova instalação do WAMP. Não é necessário copiar os bancos de dados instalados por dados WAMP padrão, ou seja, "mysql", "performance_schema" e "teste".
Agora reinicie o servidor WAMP, e ir para o phpMyAdmin. Você vai notar que os nomes dos bancos de dados estão presentes, mas as mesas estão vazias ... Não se desespere, isso é normal, vamos restaurar o seu conteúdo.
Volte para a pasta de dados do seu servidor antigo: "D: \ wamp \ bin \ mysql \ mysql5.1.53 \ data \". Um arquivo chamado "ibdata1" deveria estar lá. Copie o.
Em seu novo servidor na pasta de dados, há também um arquivo "ibdata1". Renomeá-lo para "ibdata.bak" em seguida, cole o "ibdata1" que foi previamente copiado do servidor antigo.
Finalmente, reinicie os serviços do WAMP. Então vá PHPmyAdmin e verificar se seus bancos de dados foram restaurados com sucesso!*

Comment: Obrigado. Isso deu certo para mim.

Answer (score 1):

Nos Bancos de Dados relacionais é usado um recurso para a segurança dos dados que é o log com ele o MySQL no caso salva todas as queries exceto as de SELECT no arquivo de log então você terá lá todos os SQLs para recuperar seu banco.

para saber onde está o arquivo de log entre no seu arquivo de configuração "my.cfn" ou procure na internet a pasta padrão.

aqui tem algumas informações:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql

Fora isso, desculpe mas é relativamente impossível.

Answer (score -1):

Faça o seguinte instale o MySql Front, para facilitar a manipulação e configure as entradas para acessar. Geralmente é assim:
[image: Configuração Inicial]

Aí depois de se conectar é só exportar sua Database pra extensão .sql

Veja abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]